# Unable To Make Spring Boot API Request Due To CORS Docker

Tags: java, spring, docker, nginx, cors

I have a React frontend app that makes an API call to a Spring boot app.

Both are in separate docker containers. When it's run locally everything is fine, however after deployment, when the call is made, I get a CORS error:

```
Access to fetch at 'http://xx.xx.xxx.xx:8080/simulations/1/ratings/1' from origin 'http://xx.xx.xxx.xx:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

I'm not sure why this is the case. To my mind I've coded up everything to allow CORS access (as I said it works locally, so I don't understand why it fails after deployment. I've read up a bit about docker and localhost but it just seems quite confusing to me at the moment.

This is my Java Security code from `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`:

```
    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("http://xx.xx.xxx.xx:3000"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET","POST"));
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }
```

`docker-compose.yml` is as follows:

```
version: '3'
services:     
  application-server:
    restart: always
    image: 'myhub/app-server:cors'
    expose:
      - '8080'
    ports:
      - '8080:8080'
    networks:
      - local      
  application-client:
    restart: always
    image: 'myhub/app-client:cors'
    ports:
      - '3000:80'
    stdin_open: true
    depends_on:
      - application-server
    networks:
      - local
networks: 
  local:
    driver: bridge
```

And finally the `nginx.conf`:

```
http
{
  server_tokens off;
  include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
  default_type application/octet-stream;

  upstream backend
  {
    server xx.xx.xxx.xx:8080;
  }

  server
  {

    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/host.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/host.error.log;


    root /var/www;
    index index.html index.htm;

    location ~* \.(?:manifest|appcache|html?|xml|json)$
    {
      expires -1;
    }

    location ~* \.(?:css|js)$
    {
      try_files $uri =404;
      expires 1y;
      access_log off;
      add_header Cache-Control "public";
    }

    # Any route containing a file extension (e.g. /devicesfile.js)
    location ~ ^.+\..+$
    {
      try_files $uri =404;
    }

    location /
    {

      root /var/www;
      index index.html;
      autoindex on;
      set $fallback_file /index.html;
      if ($http_accept !~ text/html)
      {
        set $fallback_file /null;
      }
      if ($uri ~ /$)
      {
        set $fallback_file /null;
      }
      try_files $uri $fallback_file;

      if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS')
      {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: $http_origin');
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: GET, POST, DELETE, PUT, PATCH, OPTIONS');
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
        add_header 'Vary: Origin');

      }

      add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' "$http_origin" always;
      add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true' always;
      add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS' always;
      add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Accept,Authorization,Cache-Control,Content-Type,DNT,If-Modified-Since,Keep-Alive,Origin,User-Agent,X-Requested-With' always;

    }
  }
}
```

What do I need to do with the containers to allow CORS access?

Answer (score 1):

First : to benefit from CORS, you don't need to focus on http client configuration.
The authorization is allowed only by the backend that answers to the question : is that host, port, request acceptable ?
Contrary to CSRF that requires configuration both client and server.

I mention that since you expose your client conf.

In any way, in Spring Boot (backend of course), we enable CORS declaratively from the `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.configure(HttpSecurity http)` method as simply as :

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
  http.cors()...
}
```

The `cors()` javadoc states that :

> Adds a CorsFilter to be used. If a bean by the name of corsFilter is
> provided, that CorsFilter is used. Else if corsConfigurationSource is
> defined, then that CorsConfiguration is used.

So first, check that.

Then you have three options :
– to do no additional thing. In this case, Spring security will use the default class provided by Spring security and the default CorsConfigurationSource bean associated to.
– to declare a bean named `corsFilter`. In this case, Spring security will use it instead of the default.
– to declare a bean named `corsConfigurationSource`. In that case, Spring will use the default CorsFilter with the custom `corsConfigurationSource` declared by the application.

You used the last way.

If it is not enough, you may have something in your `WebSecurity` configs that prevents the CORS filter to be handled at the right time.
Add that property and take time to analyse what Spring Security does about CORS :

```
logging.level.org.springframework.security=DEBUG
```

[I wrote that post](http://myjavaadventures.com/blog/2019/11/09/spring-boot-angular-and-cors/) some months ago. Maybe it could help you.

Comment: Thank you @davidxxx. What I don’t understand is why the call is fine when deployed locally, but once I put it up on a cloud server the CORS becomes an issue. I have actually also done the WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.configure(HttpSecurity http) method before I posted this, but it still doesn’t work. Which is why I’m wondering if it’s something to do with Docker.

Comment: You are welcome : ) You refer to cloud now ? I though that you used only docker and docker-compose. Maybe the URL specified in the CORS configuration is not correct.

Comment: Ah yes, sorry maybe I was not so clear in my original question. With Docker, I have managed to deploy this app locally and all the API calls from cross origin are fine. However once I deploy it to a cloud server, it's unable to recognise an API call to `localhost:8080` so I have had to change the address to the actual server IP `xx.xx.xxx.xx:8080`. I have checked and the address is correct, but the CORS issue remains.

Comment: I understand. But for the CORS part, are you sure that the client URL is right ? 
To ensure that, try with all catch : `corsConfiguration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("*"));`. If that works the issue is the url that you enter in the CORS config. Otherwise, try with the security debug flag as explained. It should help

Comment: Hmm... I have tried to catch all now, and it seems when I open up "xx.xx.xxx.xx:3000" I now get an `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` instead of the application UI...

Comment: Sorry, no idea in your specific case (cloud). I will repeat : enable the security debug and read logs, it should give your some hints.

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you find the solution?